# Identifier expected on basic C# program

Tags: c#

I'm starting learning C# and I created a small program to show the differences between float and double but I'm having a problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercicio1
{
   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float floatPI = 3.14783,141592653589793238f;
            double doublePI = 3,141592653589793238;

            Console.WriteLine("Float PI: " + floatPI);
            Console.WriteLine("Double PI: " + doublePI);
        }
   }
}
```

I'm getting Identifier expected on line 13 and 14.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, you have two decimal notations in "3.14783,141592653589793238f"

Comment: You need to use `.` instead of `,`

Comment: Yep, that was my problem, just replaced , with . and everything working fine. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using (,) when you should be using (.) if you change the commas to points it will work. Also you can't have this

```
float floatPI = 3.14783,141592653589793238f;
```

it should be this :

```
float floatPI = 3.14783141592653589793238f;
```

Answer (score 2):

the commas in those line in the middle of the number are problematic.
after the comma it expects another identifier (a new variable declaration).

Answer (score 2):

The commas.

Try:

```
float floatPI = 3.14783141592653589793238f;
double doublePI = 3.141592653589793238;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution, replace the "," with "." and it works. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma from the float:

```
  var floatPI = 3.14783141592653589793238f;
```

and change the comma to a decimal point in the double

```
  var doublePI = 3.141592653589793238;
```

I've changed to *var* but you can be explicit if you prefer. If you use *var* and mouse over the variable in VS you can see the variable types are correct.